# what is the best way to populate a picker view with JSON data in swift?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, uipickerview

i am building a COVID-19 app tracker on IOS.

In order to display the data by country, I have built a pickerView that will contain all the country names.

thanks to an HTTP cal, I have managed to get the JSON data i.e the name of each country. ideally I wish to append each value to an array that in turn will populate the pickerView.

Is that possible ? If yes, how would I do that ?

I am also open to other ways to do it. Here is my code :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var confirmedCasesLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var deathsLabel: UILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var recoveriesLabel: UILabel!

 //MARK: - Relevant variables
 private let covidUrl: String = "https://corona-api.com/countries"
 var countryArray: [String] = [String]()


 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     countryPickerView.delegate = self
     countryPickerView.dataSource = self

     //
     httpCall()
 }


 /*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */

 //MARK: - Functions that handles picker view delegates and data source
 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     return countryArray.count
    }

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
     return countryArray[row]
 }

 //MARK: - HTTP CALL - GET COUNTRY DATA
 func httpCall() {
     request(covidUrl, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
         if response.result.isSuccess {
             //test just print some data
             let dataJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
             //print(dataJSON)
             //on va identifier chaque pays + l'ajouter au tableau des pays
//                let countryNameJSON = dataJSON["data"][99]["name"]
//                print(countryNameJSON)
             for country in 0...99 {
                 let countryNameJSON = dataJSON["data"][country]["name"].stringValue
                 print(countryNameJSON)
                 //on ajoute ce nom au tabeleau de pays
                 //self.countryArray.append(countryNameJSON)
             }

         }
     }
 }



}
```

Comment: Create a custom struct, load the data with `Codable` and populate the picker view with `countryArray[row].name`. No loops, no obsolete SwiftyJSON, no mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a struct which conforms to `Decodable` protocol and add the required attributes

```
struct Country: Decodable {
    var name: String?
}
```

- Create an `Country` object type array named `countryArray` in your class
- Perform the HTTP call
- Fetch the data from the server
- Parse the and load into `countryArray` object using `JSONDecoder`
- Reload the countryPickerView after parsing

Please follow the sample below

```
class YourClass {

    @IBOutlet weak var countryPickerView: UIPickerView!

    var countryArray = [Country]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        countryPickerView.delegate = self
        countryPickerView.dataSource = self
        httpCall()
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return countryArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return countryArray[row].name
    }

    //MARK: - HTTP CALL - GET COUNTRY DATA
    func httpCall() {
        request(covidUrl, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let countryArray = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: #yourJsonData#)
                countryPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Since the `Country` object conforms to `Decodable` protocol the parsing will be done with no loops given that the `Struct` matches with your JSON schema.